# pyspark Can't running in pycharm but run well in shell in Ubuntu

Tags: python, pyspark, pycharm

I deployed pyspark in ubuntu,and run it well in shell.but when I run the same code in pycharm,it got some problem.I also set the  environment variable in pyCharm as the same as the value in /etc/profile.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rw4EU.png)

could someone help me?

Comment: Don't post your code as image! Edit your post, then copy past it into your post! and pu some format on it click the `{}` button

Comment: thank you ,I try it